# Exporting a graphics layer to either a shape or CAD file from Silverlight (c#)

Tags: c#, silverlight, arcgis, esri

Using ArcGIS API for Silverlight 2.4. I have a graphics layer and would like to export it to either of the above mentioned formats (shp or dwg). Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could accomplish this? I am using Silverlight 5.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, exporting graphics layers isn't supported. I wrote my own class that goes through the graphics layer and serializes the symbols and geometry for each graphic to XML. I am not at my work computer at the moment so I can't share it with you.

Comment: hmm...that's a pity. Thanks, maybe when get in you can shoot me a link with that serialization strategy.